# Customizing Image picker by media type in Swift/Objective-c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, imagepicker, uiimagepickercontrollermediatype

I want to show category wise (like still photo, live photo, video, slow-mo etc) media to select one or more images/video.
When user select "Live Photo button" then only live photos  would be come.
When user select "Slow-mo Button" then only slow-mo videos would be come and so on.
I'm trying to use `UIImagePickerController` but maybe it doesn't support customization. 
I've found [this](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker) library but I always got this [error](https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker/issues/93).

Are there any alternative library or approaches  available in Swift/Objective-C (iOS version at least 12)?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `PHPickerViewController`

You can play with `PHPickerConfiguration`to show only certain media types or limiting the max number of selections, for example:

```
let configuration = PHPickerConfiguration()
configuration.selectionLimit = 10
configuration.filter = .livePhotos
```

Then *init* `PHPickerViewController` with your configuration, and use delegate methods as you wish.

```
let controller = PHPickerViewController(configuration: configuration)
controller.delegate = self
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: is it available for iOS >=10? I can't found any module like  PHPickerViewController

Comment: I got it. But I need to support my app for at least iOS 12.0 users. But PHPickerViewController is supported only for iOS 14+

Comment: then I think you need to use one custom library like https://github.com/DragonCherry/AssetsPickerViewController

Comment: I have used it( AssetsPickerViewController library) now. But it doesn't show any other sub category . When I added sub category it always shows empty view.